# SQL: changing IN to EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to improve the performance of my code. I read that exists is faster than in and wanted to change my code to reflect that. Currently, my code is:

```sql
SELECT id,
       product_name,
       type,
       quantity
FROM   producttable
WHERE  op = 'o'
       AND bl = 'l'
       AND ( LEFT(id, 3) IN ( '100', '507', '508', '515' )
              OR ( LEFT(id, 3) = '506'
                   AND LEFT(id, 4) <> '5634' ) )
```

Would changing the "in" in the where statement to exists help with performance, and if so, what would the syntax be?

Comment: The lowest hanging fruit for optimization here is getting `LEFT()` out of your `WHERE` clause. Normalize your data (take the ID column apart so that the keys which you seek are truly unique... or otherwise stop searching on a few characters in a column... and index the column).

Comment: Why do you have <> '5643'? You have a list of valid values which would already exclude that.

Answer (score 2):

If you would rewrite the where clause as follows, you might improve performance:

```
SELECT Id,
       Product_Name,
       Type,
       Quantity
FROM Producttable
WHERE Op = 'o'
      AND Bl = 'l'
      AND ( Id LIKE ('100%') OR 
            Id LIKE ('507%') OR
            Id LIKE ('508%') OR 
            Id LIKE ('515%') OR 
            Id LIKE ('506%') OR 
            Id LIKE ('5634%') )
```

Using functions in a where clause can hurt performance.

Comment: Yup, with the proviso that there's an index of sorts on `Id`, `Bl` and `Op`, and that the filters are selective.

Comment: This is definitely the right idea but this doesn't quite get the correct results. They want to exclude 5634. But not really sure why they bothered with the <> part since the list of included values would already eliminate that one.

Answer (score 0):

First, in spite of much upvoted answers indicating to the contrary, exists vs in having a better performance is a myth. There are no dedicated operations in the plan to these different syntax options - only the common (anti-) semi join operators.

Second, if you would use exists() in your query, you would have to create a table with the values. Sounds cumbersome.

Instead, I recommend SQL_M's answer. When you use any function on a `Id`, like left(), the optimizer will disregard any index on that field. But, when you use `LIKE` without a *starting* `%`, this uses the index because it actually creates a small range:

```
>previous value and <next value
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
Select id, 
      product_name, 
      type, 
      quantity 
from Producttable 
Where op = 'o' and bl ='l' 
and (left(id, 3) in ('100', '507', '508', '515') ) 
union 
Select id, 
      product_name, 
      type, 
      quantity 
from Producttable Where op = 'o' 
and bl ='l' and (left(id, 3) = '506' and left(id, 4)
```

---

HTH
Regards Alexander

Comment: Code only answers are very rarely good. Can you explain why you think this is an improvement? This is very likely going to be even slower because of the UNION. And at best it is no improvement for performance at all.